# Does there exist an iPhone application that can call an online API (RESTful or otherwise) triggered by geofences?

Tags: applications, geolocation

I've pretty much stated the entire question in the title:

I'm looking for an iPhone application that can call an online API (preferably RESTful but I'll accept anything) as a reaction to triggering a geofence.

So, as a stupid example, a tweet could be sent out automatically when I arrive at my house. The iPhone would see the geofence trigger, the application would be invoked, which would call the Twitter API to send the tweet.

Comment: So kind of like [boxcar](http://boxcar.io/download) but in reverse where the general program gets handed various API to call when a reminder is triggered?

Comment: Exactly. In fact finding something like Boxcar was the first part of what I needed. (I ended up going with Prowl). Now I want to be able to trigger events in my house (turning on the lights through a REST API, for example) when I pull up to the house.

Comment: Perhaps someone in jailbreak land has hacked the reminders app since it has everything you want except an URL to call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Locative can do this:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/locative/id725198453?mt=8

https://github.com/LocativeHQ